# Creating XPATH for an element - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Can anyone help me to derive the xpath for the below HTML. I am new to selenium.

I need to get rupees for each span but the problem is both the element have same class names. How do I create unique xpath to find the elements

```
<div class="pu-price">
<div class="pu-border-top">
<div class="pu-final">
<span class="fk-font-17 fk-bold">Rs. 5,557</span>
</div>
<div class="pu-emi fk-font-12">EMI from Rs. 270 </div>

<div class="pu-price">
<div class="pu-border-top">
<div class="pu-final">
<span class="fk-font-17 fk-bold">Rs. 9,997</span>
</div>
<div class="pu-emi fk-font-12">EMI from Rs. 500 </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And if I remember `XPath` correctly you can just count through same objects.

Comment: i manged to get the first price wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='pu-final']/span[1]")).getText().replace("Rs."," ");  how do i count objects?

Answer (score 2):

my suggestion is to use xpath that is more general to get all the elements that contains your span, for example:
xpath: 
    **"//div[@class='pu-final']/"**
or if u want to be more specific:
xpath:
     ***//div[@class='pu-final' and contains(.,'Rs')]***
this will bring u all the elements in the page that contains Rs and u can put them in some list:

```
public static List<WebElement> getElements(String selector) {
        By locator = By.xpath(selector);
        List<WebElement> webElements = driver.findElements(locator);
        return webElements;
    }
```

then u can do whatever u want on the list u have.

Comment: Thank you and could you please share if you have any tutorial about XPATH derivation technique

Comment: the best way that i use is in the browser: open console and type $x("") between them type the xpath and u can see the results ,  i dont like to use the addons

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
(//div[@class = 'pu-final']/span)[1]
```

to get the first one, and

```
(//div[@class = 'pu-final']/span)[2]
```

for the second. This is probably what bish meant about counting through the selected nodes.

Comment: Yep that's what I mean :) Thank you for an example!